# How to run Java programs over ssh?

Tags: java, unix, ssh, terminal, distributed-computing

Let's say I make a Java project in Eclipse that has 3-10 classes and one of which has a main(String[] args) method that starts the whole program and takes 4 arguments at the command line.   Let's also say that this project has 6-10 .jar files in src/lib that it needs to run.

If I have ssh access to another computer (UNIX on both ends) and I want to run this program, how exactly do I go about doing so?

I ask because I have been doing some distributed computing projects and I need to run my program on multiple machines but I am a total command line noob and I don't have physical access to all of the machines.

Edit:
Seems I need to SCP the files over.  Can someone show me the particular command that makes the  Java program run?  Including what directory I should run it from and how to include the JAR dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you use ssh to log into a remote computer, and then you run programs from that machine's storage, using that machine's resources.

So if you want to run your Java program on a different machine, you'd need to copy the required files there, then ssh to that machine and run the program from the remote command line.

Answer (score 7):

to run

***java -jar thejarfile.jar "arg1" "arg2" "ectect.."***

if you want to run it in the background ***java -jar thejarfile.jar "arg1" "arg2" &***

to kill it if its in the background ***ps -aux*** to get the id and then ***kill (id number)***

Answer (score 2):

You write a tiny bootstrap program that will be your MicroKernel. You SCP that MicroKernel to the remote machine. This program will use a custom ClassLoader to pull the rest of the dependencies for your real application down into memory or some storage onto the remote machine. Look into the URL ClassLoader for some help as it can load JAR files from HTTP addresses.

Or you can just zip up your whole program, SCP it to the remote machine, unzip it then run 'java' like normal. If you have SSH access you should have access to scp files onto that machine. If not you can always SSH into the remove machine then `scp` them from your machine.

Example:

```
ssh myname@myremotemachine
> mkdir /location/to/program
> scp myname@mydevmachine:/location/to/program/* /location/to/program
```

This all works really well if you have your SSH keys setup properly and don't have to put in a password.